# Displaying a DecimalField with currency in the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, decimal, currency-formatting

I have multiple models with multiple DecimalField representing money, like 100.34 EUR.

My goal was to display the currency in the admin list view, like shown in this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyaaC.png

However I couldn't find a way to do it for every money field.

I tried creating a custom MoneyField, inheriting from DecimalField and changind the **unicode** representation, but it didn't work.

I also tried with https://github.com/jakewins/django-money but I had no luck.

I investigated the source code of django admin and I finally found the problem:

In django.admin.contrib.admin.util.py in the display_for_field function it checks if the value is an instance of DecimalField. If that's the case it displays it like a Decimal number.

```
elif isinstance(field, models.DecimalField):
    return formats.number_format(value, field.decimal_places)
```

It makes sense, but it prevents me from displaying the EUR symbol/text in the admin.

How can I solve this problem?

I know that I could simply use a method for each field that display the formatted value as a string, but I wanted to know if there was a DRYer way.

Answer (score 11):

For display in the admin list, you can make a custom function in your `ModelAdmin` class, which will be called to format each value:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('formatted_amount', ...other fields...,)

    def formatted_amount(self, obj):
        # obj is the Model instance

        # If your locale is properly set, try also:
        # locale.currency(obj.amount, grouping=True)
        return '%.2f EUR' % obj.amount
```

Comment: Sure, but i have to make a method for each field. It doesn't feel like a DRY solution

Comment: You might also add `formatted_amount.short_description = 'amount'` on a separate line to fix the column header.

Comment: this solution does not support sorting values in admin list

Comment: @DataGreed in order to add a sorting just add(based on the example above) formatted_amount.admin_order_field = "amount"

Answer (score 1):

Or create a class like this and inherit from it

```
class ImprovedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Handles column formatting in list display"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def generate_formatter(name, str_format):
            formatter = lambda o: str_format%(getattr(o, name) or 0)
            formatter.short_description = name
            formatter.admin_order_field = name
            return formatter

        all_fields = []
        for f in self.list_display:
            if isinstance(f, basestring):
                all_fields.append(f)
            else:
                new_field_name = f[0]+'_formatted'
                setattr(self, new_field_name, generate_formatter(f[0], f[1]))
                all_fields.append(new_field_name)
        self.list_display = all_fields

        super(ImprovedAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MyModelAdmin(ImprovedAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', ('amount', '%.2f EUR'), ('interest', '%.2f %%'))
```

Comment: I no longer have the codebase, but this looks like it might work :S

I'll try when I have time to test it so I can accept the answer

Comment: NB: in python 3, `basestring` changes to just `str`, and `super(ImprovedAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` to just `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to display like **"34.00 EUR"** so that you can always display a number with the 2nd decimal place even if the decimal place is **zero**.

#### <The 1st way>

Define `price` with [models.DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) and `decimal_places=2` as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2, # Here
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(99999),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ],
        default=0
    )
```

Then, define `price_with_EUR()` then assign it to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'name', 
        'price_with_EUR' # Here
    ]

    def price_with_EUR(self, obj): # Here
        return f'{self.price} EUR'
```

#### <The 2nd way>

Define `price_with_EUR()` with **`@property` decorator** as shown below in **"models.py"**.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(99999),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ],
        default=0
    )

    @property # Here
    def price_with_EUR(self):
        return f'{self.price} EUR'
```

Then, assign `price_with_EUR()` to `list_display` as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'name', 
        'price_with_EUR' # Here
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `0.12` version of `django-money` money representation was partially supported for Django admin.

Since `0.12` version (released on 22.10.2017) all `MoneyField` representations (including Django's admin) could be configured with special [formatter](https://github.com/django-money/django-money#adding-a-new-currency).

```
import moneyed
from moneyed.localization import _FORMATTER
from decimal import ROUND_HALF_EVEN


BOB = moneyed.add_currency(
    code='BOB',
    numeric='068',
    name='Peso boliviano',
    countries=('BOLIVIA', )
)

# Currency Formatter will output 2.000,00 Bs.
_FORMATTER.add_sign_definition(
    'default',
    BOB,
    prefix=u'Bs. '
)

_FORMATTER.add_formatting_definition(
    'es_BO',
    group_size=3, group_separator=".", decimal_point=",",
    positive_sign="",  trailing_positive_sign="",
    negative_sign="-", trailing_negative_sign="",
    rounding_method=ROUND_HALF_EVEN
)
```