# Format decimal on definition in Admin Panel Django

Tags: python, django

I create a definition to get the percentage of completed tasks associated with a project.

```
class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    #...
    def percentage(sef, obj):
        return obj.todo_set.filter(state = True).count() * 100 / obj.todo_set.all().count()
    #...
    list_display = ['project_title', 'category_list', 'date_format', 'crq_count', 'task_count', 'percentage', 'file_count', 'state']
```

[image]

I want to eliminate the decimals and transform it into whole numbers

Finally, the idea is that if all the tasks are completed, the project status should go to finished

```
class Project(models.Model):
    #...
    state = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null = True, default = False)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18759765, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25480018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the value you obtain when retrieving the percentage:

```
class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    # …
    
    def percentage(sef, obj):
        return round(
           obj.todo_set.filter(state=True).count() * 100 / obj.todo_set.all().count()
        )
```